# How to use an `onClick` event to stop calling a function which is called by the useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, clearinterval, use-effect

How to use an `onClick` event to stop a recurring function call? The function call is recurring due to using `useEffect`, `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

An example shown in [this article](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks), the below code will run forever. How to stop the function from being called once the `<header></header>` is clicked?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const IntervalExample = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {seconds} seconds have elapsed since mounting.
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IntervalExample;
```

Comment: You basiclly can't because you declared it a const with nothing that can change his value inside the useEffect, so nothing will ever be able to reach it . But you can  declare it outside the use effect and change the value of `interval` with a useEffect on `seconds` or something like .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another state called `running`, and make the `useEffect` dependent on it. Whenever `running` is toggled to `false`, the interval would be cleared by the cleanup function of `useEffect`. Since `running` is `false` we skip setting a new interval. Whenever it's toggled to `true`, it will be restarted.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const IntervalExample = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(true);
  
  const toggleRunning = useCallback(
    () => setRunning(run => !run)
  , []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!running) {
      // setSeconds(0); // if you want to reset it as well
      return;
    }
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [running]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {seconds} seconds have elapsed since mounting.
      </header>
      
      <button
        onClick={toggleRunning}
        >
        {running ? 'running' : 'stopped'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <IntervalExample />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Have a question on this approach, when we update `running` hook, it won't unmount the component so the cleanup won't work. And you will generate a new interval id at this time and the old interval won't be cleared. Am I right?

Comment: The cleanup is called whenever the [dependencies change](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect): "Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect.". If not the setInterval would continue to call `setSeconds`.

Answer (score 1):

I would pull out the interval const from the useEffect function like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const IntervalExample = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  let interval;

  useEffect(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


  const handleClick = () => {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        {seconds} seconds have elapsed since mounting.
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IntervalExample;
```

Comment: `interval` seems to be undefined inside the `handleClick` function and the above code doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I think by stopping you mean to say `clearInterval` on a click event. So the best way to hold an interval id in a new state variable.

```
const IntervalExample = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [currentIntervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    setIntervalId(interval);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(currentIntervalId);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header" onClick={stopInterval}>
        {seconds} seconds have elapsed since mounting.
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};
```

- Why in state? 
  Because this will give you more flexibility to restart the interval again or to stop whenever you want based on event.

**Note:** You can also put this in a variable defined outside the scope of `useEffect`.